# goroutine shared variable display

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a following piece of `Go` code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func f(name string, x *int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        *x++
        fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", name, *x)
    }
}

func main() {
    var x int
    go f("routine 1", &x)
    go f("routine 2", &x)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

The output generated by this code looks like this:

```
routine 1: 1
routine 1: 3
routine 2: 2
routine 2: 5
routine 2: 6
routine 2: 7
routine 2: 8
routine 1: 4
routine 1: 9
routine 1: 10
```

I am confused about the following:

```
routine 1: 1
routine 1: 3
routine 2: 2
```

Specifically `routine 2: 2`. In my view it should be `routine 2: 3`. Here is why I think so.

At first routine 1 executes, increments x by 1 and displays it (x = 1). That's why we are seeing `routine 1: 1`. Then routine 2 executes and increments x by 1 (x = 2), however before displaying it the `Go` scheduler stops it and switches back to routine 1. Routine 1 increments x by 1 (x = 3) and displays it, which is why we are seeing `routine 1: 3`. Then `Go` scheduler switches back to routine 2. At this point routine 2 is displaying x which should be equal to 3 however what we see being displayed is `routine 2: 2`. Can someone explain what is going on? I feel I'm missing something very important but I don't know what it is.

**EDIT**
Let me clarify that I created a race condition on purpose. I just wanted to see what was happening. However I can't explain why it is happening. In my mind I should be seeing `routine: 2: 3` but I'm seeing `routine 2: 2`. Can someone explain why? Maybe actually walk through the code and point out what I'm missing. I would genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: The behavior is undefined because there is a data race.

Comment: Try running with the race detector to see where the problem lies.

Comment: @MuffinTop I've provided additional explanation

Comment: @squiguy I've provided additional explanation

Comment: You're going to have to look at the machine code. The value might be in a register. It might be a CPU race problem as well because unlocked increment operations on an integer are not guaranteed to be visible to other CPU cores in any rational way.

Comment: In other words, the CPU is pretty much free to make an increment operation into a load, add, store, and if there was a stream of them the internal microcode may even just say, "7 increments, lets load i and add 7"

Comment: Oh and you don't want to get into how speculative execution can interact with cached values from other cores.

Comment: *"Let me clarify that I created a race condition on purpose":* this means that you created code with *undefined behavior* on purpose. Don't try to explain the behavior you see, because ***the behavior undefined***.

Answer (score 0):

In Golang concurrent code execution order is upredictible. You may want to use [mutex](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) or [channel](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) to work with shared variable from goroutines.

Comment: I've provided additional explanation in the post.

Comment: *"In Golang concurrent code execution order is upredictible"* -> not really, Go has a very clear memory model spec that states very precisely how well-defined programs must behave. OP's problem isn't about "unpredictability of concurrent code in Go", but it's that OP's code has undefined behavior, *by definition*: it violates the memory model.